# ¿es necesario importar las dependencias de un jar que es dependencia de mi proyecto?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

Al intentar usar un jar (propio) en mi proyecto, gradle me está generando un error al no encontrar una dependencia que usa el jar, ¿Debo importar ésta dependencia que falta en mi proyecto? ¿Por qué pasa este comportamiento ? ¿Cuál es la buena práctica en estos casos?

Comment: Si estamos hablando de aplicacion stadalone en efecto tienes que agregar la depedencia que necesite tu proyecto para ser ejecutada en otra maquina en cambio si hablamos de una aplicacion que corra dentro un contenedor de aplicaciones o servidor este generalmente proporciona la mayoria de  las dependencias

Comment: Depende para que tipo de aplicación lo requieras pero en efecto sino se encuentra la librería deberías agregarla. Sin embargo, lo recomendable es asegurarse que el jar esté bien generado y posteriormente realizar las configuraciones necesarias en el `build.gradle`, darle un refresh all del gradle de tu aplicación y ésto deberá proporcionarte las dependencias.